# Algebraic structure $(Z^{3},\star)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help solving this task, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me.

The task is:

Prove the associativity of an algebraic structure
$(Z^{3},\star) $
if operation $\star$ is defined with
$(a,b,c)\star(x,y,z)=(a+(-1)^{b}x,b+(-1)^{c}y,c+(-1)^{a}z)$

I tried this:

$((a,b,c)\star(x,y,z))\star(d,e,f) =  (a,b,c)\star(((x,y,z)\star(d,e,f)))$

$(a+(-1)^{b}x,b+(-1)^{c}y,c+(-1)^{a}z)\star (d,e,f)=(a,b,c)\star(x+(-1)^{y}d,y+(-1)^{z}e,z+(-1)^{x}f)$

And now, I don t know what to do next?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Well, the problem is that you've still got some $\star$s in there, right? So start by getting rid of those.

Answer (score 1):

If we expand out the left hand side, we obtain \begin{align*}((a,b,c)\star(x,y,z))\star(d,e,f) &= (a + (-1)^bx,b+(-1)^cy,c+(-1)^az)\star(d,e,f)\\&= (a + (-1)^bx + (-1)^{b+(-1)^cy}d ,b + (-1)^cy + (-1)^{c + (-1)^az}e,c+(-1)^az+(-1)^{a+(-1)^bx}f\end{align*}

The right hand side similar expands as

\begin{align*}(a,b,c)\star((x,y,z)\star(d,e,f))&= (a,b,c)\star(x + (-1)^yd,y+(-1)^ze,z+(-1)^xf)\\&=(a + (-1)^b(x + (-1)^yd), b + (-1)^c(y + (-1)^ze),c+(-1)^a(z + (-1)^xf)\end{align*}

So now, all we need to do is show that these two are equal. To keep track of that, we'll subtract them, and see what we end up with:

\begin{align*}&(a,b,c)\star((x,y,z)\star(d,e,f))-((a,b,c)\star(x,y,z))\star(d,e,f)\\&=((-1)^{b + (-1)^cy}d-(-1)^{b+y}d,(-1)^{c+(-1)^az}e-(-1)^{c+z}e,(-1)^{a+(-1)^bz}f-(-1)^{c+z}f)
\\&=\left((-1)^bd\left(\left((-1)^{(-1)^c}\right)^y-(-1)^{y}\right),(-1)^ce\left(\left((-1)^{(-1)^a}\right)^z-(-1)^z\right),(-1)^af\left(\left((-1)^{(-1)^b}\right)^x-(-1)^x\right)\right).\end{align*}

Now, note that $(-1)^{(-1)^n} = -1$ for all $n$ (since both $1$ and $-1$ are odd), so that last line simplifies down to

$$\left((-1)^bd\left((-1)^y-(-1)^y\right),(-1)^ce\left((-1)^z-(-1)^z\right),(-1)^af\left((-1)^x-(-1)^x\right)\right) = 0.$$

Thus, $\star$ is associative.